# How can I use versioning in S3 with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using a versioned S3 bucket, with boto3. How can I retrieve all versions for a given key (or even all versions for all keys)  ? I can do this:

```
for os in b.objects.filter(Prefix=pref):
    print("os.key")
```

but that gives me only the most recent version for each key.

Comment: the phrasing of the question is the versions of objects, not the version ids. While the existing two answers give how to get the version ids, they do not show how to get the versions. I've added a third answer which shows how to get all version ids and then use them to get the versions of the objects.

Answer (score 23):

```
import boto3

bucket = 'bucket name'
key = 'key'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
versions = s3.Bucket(bucket).object_versions.filter(Prefix=key)

for version in versions:
    obj = version.get()
    print(obj.get('VersionId'), obj.get('ContentLength'), obj.get('LastModified'))
```

I can't take credit as I had the same question but I found this [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/27692301-aws-s3-dowload-small-files)

Comment: Great, thanks! I am not working on this project anymore, but it nice to see that there is a solution. As to an explation of the code, well. First you specify the bucket you after, and then the key, which tells s3 which objects in the bucket you want. Then you iterate over all versions, and print the versionId and the length.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't actually say how to get the object using the VersionId, for example, but presumably it's possible to filter the objects that way...

Comment: How do I know what the current version is? My first approach would be to order by `LastModified`, but maybe the last version is deleted?

Comment: aws s3api get-object --bucket BUCKETNAME --key KEY --version-id VERSION /path/to/filetosave.jpg

Comment: Be careful, this will also return versions of objects which START with this key, e.g. 'key1', 'key2' etc. To exclude these the for loop needs to filter these out.

Answer (score 8):

boto3 s3 client has a `list_object_versions` method.

```
resp = client.list_object_versions(Prefix=prefix, Bucket=bucket)

for obj in [*resp['Versions'], *resp.get('DeleteMarkers', [])]:
    print(f"Key: {obj['Key']}")
    print(f"VersionId: {obj['VersionId']}")
    print(f"LastModified: {obj['LastModified']}")
    print(f"IsLatest: {obj['IsLatest']}")
    print(f"Size: {obj.get('Size', 0)/1e6}")
```

supposing you wanted to delete all but the current version, you could do so by adding the objects where not `IsLatest` to a `to_delete` list, then running the following:

```
for obj in to_delete:
    print(client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=obj['Key'], VersionId=obj['VersionId']))
```

Answer (score 6):

The existing answers describe how to get the ***version ids*** of the objects. We're interested in using ***versions*** of the object(s) this usually involves accessing part, or all of the objects.

First get the version ids. I'll use `al76`'s answer here for getting ***version ids*** to illustrate both `boto3.resource` and `boto3.client` examples.

```
import boto3
from collections import deque


bucket = 'bucket name'
key = 'key'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
versions = s3.Bucket(bucket).object_versions.filter(Prefix=key)
s3_object_versions = deque()

for version in versions:
    obj = version.get()
    s3_object_versions.appendleft(obj.get('VersionId'))
```

Next we need to get the actual versioned objects, there are a couple ways to do this, depending on whether you have a s3 resource or the s3 client. Given that we got the version ids with the resource we'll start there.

```
# using the first version of the object
obj_version = s3.ObjectVersion(bucket, key, s3_object_versions[0]).get()

# if this object is really large this loop might execute for awhile
for event in obj_version['Body']:
    print(event)
```

Note that each `event` is a `botocore.response.StreamingBody` object and may not correspond to a row if your object is a csv file (etc).

Now as an alternate approach, you might have an s3 *client* rather than an s3 resource object. In the s3 resource you can access the client via `.meta`. Here is code:

```
response = s3.meta.client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, VersionId=s3_object_versions[-1])

# same caveat as above, for loop may run for awhile if object is large
for event in response['Body']:
    print(event)
```

A third option which is very similar to the first one, directly using the resource, bucket and object.

```
object = s3.Bucket(bucket).Object(key).get()
object_version = object.Version(s3_object_versions[0]).get()
#  again careful if object is large-will run awhile and fill stdout
for event in object_version['Body']:
    print(event)
```

A fourth option-also using the s3 *client* is to download the file directly.

```
object_original_version = s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket, key, '/tmp/' + key, ExtraArgs={'VersionId': s3_object_versions[0]})
```

Then you can read the file from `/tmp` via `open()` call or something more specialized for the file format.

In your code you'll likely want to wrap these with `try/except` etc. to handle errors unless this is prototyping/experimental work.

Comment: Super. Thanks Lucas.

Comment: This is perfect (almost). Just one caveat on the "third option". The way it's described, you get the object when you already have the object (since you've done a `get()` already to build `s3_object_versions`). If you really want to use the "third option", you probably want to just use the `id` property of the S3.ObjectVersion object stored in `versions` as argument of `object.Version()`, and bypass the logic that creates `s3_object_versions` altogether (or replace `get()` with `head()` in that logic if you need more details about each version).

Comment: @marcodb good point-my intent here was more to demonstrate the options available.