# How to determine s3 folder size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of s3 folders for different projects/clients and I would like to estimate total size (so I can for instance consider reducing sizes/cost). What is a good way to determine this?

Comment: Similar to: [How to find size of a folder inside an S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49759940/174777)

Comment: Sub-folders too, or just top-level folders?

Answer (score 1):

I can do this with a combination of Python and the AWS client:

```
import os

bucket_rows = os.popen('aws s3 ls').split(chr(10))
sizes = dict()

for bucket in bucket_rows:
    buck = bucket.split(' ')[-1]    # the full row contains additional information
    cmd = f"aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://{buck}/ | grep 'Total'"
    sizes[buck] = os.popen(cmd).read()
```

Comment: `aws s3 ls s3://bucket/path/to/data/ --summarize --human-readable --recursive | grep 'Total'` is an excellent way to quickly get subtotal size. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/84815/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket) AWS CLI natively supports --query parameter with can determine the size of every object in S3 bucket.

```
 aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME --output json --query "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]"
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the magic

```bash
for bucket_name in `aws s3 ls | awk '{print $3}'`; do
  echo "$bucket_name"
  aws s3 ls s3://$bucket_name --recursive --summarize | tail -n2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check via console.

1. If you mention a folder by folder and not bucket, then just select that object go to "action" drop down and select "Get total size"
2. If you mean bucket by folder , then go to management tab and in that go to metrics it will show entire bucket size