# Fetch list of first level directories in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

In my S3 buckets there are many directories at first level. Each containing data of it's own.

```
- Bucket
   -- dir_1
       -- file1
        -- file2
   -- dir_2
       -- somefile
```

I want to fetch total size (including all the subobjects under it)  of each first level object (dir_1, dir_2) in the bucket. I tried both **ListObjects** and **ListObjectsV2** with different **Prefix parameter** values but either it's giving no data or all the data including object within objects

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch size of each first level object"? Do you mean you would like to know the total storage space taken by all files within `dir_1`? Or are you simply wanting to see the size of individual objects in the top-most directory?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to get total size of dir_1 including all of it's sub objects

Comment: Directories do not actually exist in Amazon S3, so I shall interpret your requirements as "calculate the total size of objects with the Prefix of `dir_1/`. You will need to calculate this yourself, as explained by @Marcin below.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there is **no API call** that can give you size of your folders/prefixes.

Normally for that you have too **iterate** over all the objects yourself, get their data and calculate the size.

Since this is a common request, there are many **recipes already made** for that. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759940/how-to-find-size-of-a-folder-inside-an-s3-bucket) or [here](https://gist.github.com/hrwgc/3fedab87eb937772ca58).

The alternative is to use [Amazon S3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html). The inventory would produce a **csv file** daily with the metadata of your objects. Then you could parse it to calculate the sizes based on the prefixes.